# How to mount a USB drive on Android Things?

Tags: linux, usb, mount, android-things

I'm attempting to read files off of a USB drive for an *Android Things* app on a *Raspberry Pi*. I'm able to scan the list of mounted devices like so:

```
public static List<File> ScanForFiles(Context context){
    ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<>();
    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/self/mountinfo"));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] columns = line.split(" ");
            Log.i(TAG, "Mounted: " + columns[4]);
            //files.addAll(getListFiles(new File(columns[4])));
        }
    } catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    printFileInformation("/proc/partitions");

    return files;
}

private static void printFileInformation(String fileName){
    Log.i("TitanTV", "Reading contents of " + fileName);

    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            Log.i("TitanTV", line);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Which displays the following output:

```
I: Mounted: /
I: Mounted: /dev
I: Mounted: /dev
I: Mounted: /dev/pts
I: Mounted: /dev/memcg
I: Mounted: /dev/cpuctl
I: Mounted: /proc
I: Mounted: /sys
I: Mounted: /sys/fs/selinux
I: Mounted: /sys/fs/pstore
I: Mounted: /acct
I: Mounted: /mnt
I: Mounted: /mnt/runtime/default/emulated
I: Mounted: /mnt/runtime/read/emulated
I: Mounted: /mnt/runtime/write/emulated
I: Mounted: /config
I: Mounted: /data
I: Mounted: /oem
I: Mounted: /gapps
I: Mounted: /storage
I: Mounted: /storage/emulated
I: Mounted: /storage/self
```

```
I: Reading contents of /proc/partitions
I: major minor  #blocks  name
I:    1        0       8192 ram0
I:    1        1       8192 ram1
I:    1        2       8192 ram2
I:    1        3       8192 ram3
I:    1        4       8192 ram4
I:    1        5       8192 ram5
I:    1        6       8192 ram6
I:    1        7       8192 ram7
I:    1        8       8192 ram8
I:    1        9       8192 ram9
I:    1       10       8192 ram10
I:    1       11       8192 ram11
I:    1       12       8192 ram12
I:    1       13       8192 ram13
I:    1       14       8192 ram14
I:    1       15       8192 ram15
I:  179        0    7761920 mmcblk0
I:  179        1      65536 mmcblk0p1
I:  179        2       1024 mmcblk0p2
I:  179        3       1024 mmcblk0p3
I:  179        4      32768 mmcblk0p4
I:  179        5      32768 mmcblk0p5
I:  179        6     524288 mmcblk0p6
I:  179        7     524288 mmcblk0p7
I:  179        8         64 mmcblk0p8
I:  179        9         64 mmcblk0p9
I:  179       10       1024 mmcblk0p10
I:  179       11      32768 mmcblk0p11
I:  179       12      32768 mmcblk0p12
I:  179       13     262144 mmcblk0p13
I:  179       14     262144 mmcblk0p14
I:  179       15    2683736 mmcblk0p15
I:    8        0    7847935 sda
I:    8        1    7845888 sda1
```

However, my thumb drive isn't apart of the list. So I'm guessing I need to mount it in some way. How can I mount the thumb drive and access the files on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ADB ONLY SOLUTION**

Seem like as of now USB drives aren't mounted automatically. In order to make your code work I had to mount it manually.

As you can see (from `/proc/partitions`) in the `/proc` partition the USB drive is detected as `sda`.

**ADB mounting**

- Make a directory to mount to

  ```
  mkdir /mnt/usb
  ```
- Mount the device

  ```
  mount -t vfat -o rw /dev/block/sda1 /mnt/usb
  ```

Now you should be able to list (and manage) the files on the USB drive both via ADB and from within the app (`/mnt/usb` will also be logged).

Comment: Right, up until the suggestion that you can do this from an app, which is deeply mistaken in both expectation and method - "su" cannot be "gained" as even when it works (unlikely here!) it applies only to the subprocess it runs, not the requesting process.

Comment: @Chris Stratton, _"su cannot be gained as even when it works (unlikely here!)"_ Why is that? Have you `list`ed `system/xbin` for any of versions of `Android Things`? `su` was shipped for the very 1st Developer Preview...

Comment: @Chris Stratton,_"it applies only to the subprocess it runs, not the requesting process"_ I never told it was the other way. You surely know how to read to/write from a subprocess programmatically. The task is not trivial and goes out of the scope of the question... Downvoting the answer seems to be unreasonable to me...

Comment: While you may be aware of more details, your post is misleading, and actively confusing people.

Comment: While this answer may offer a solution through adb, I think it's clear from the formulation of the OP that the author is looking for a solution to do so programmatically. To be clear: *unless you have root access on Android Things, this solution will not work*, and rooting the device is really an unrealistic approach here.

Comment: Paul Lammertsma, ...another downvote...you seem to be a friend of Chris Stratton... _"I think it's clear from the formulation of the OP that the author is looking for a solution to do so programmatically"_ Well, OP'd hardly agree with you. _"and rooting the device is really an unrealistic approach here"_ what is it based on? It's interesting to see how people that have some knowledge of Android internals think Android Things is backed as a regular stock phone while lots of `/system/bin` binaries of Android Things are world-executable.

Answer (score 1):

I have made an script that every 10 seconds if detects a usb storage units mounts it automatically, the only problem is to launch it on Boot, maybe this could help you, I have my post here:
[Execute Script on Boot Android Things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51374725/execute-script-on-boot-android-things)

And the script:

```
while true; do

if [ "$( ls -l /dev/block/sd* | wc -l)" -ge 1 ];

then echo "partition available"

if [ "$( mount | grep  "usbAlv" -c)" -ge 1 ]; #if partition not mounted

then echo " Unit Mounted"

else

echo "not  mounted"


//if folder where we mount the partition doesnt exist

if [ !"$( ls -l /sdcard/usbAlv | wc -l)" -ge 1 ];

then mkdir /sdcard/usbAlv

fi

su root << EOSU

mount -t vfat -o rw /dev/block/sd* /sdcard/usbAlv

EOSU

fi

else

echo "not partition available"

fi

sleep 10;

done
```

Hope it helps, i guess now is the only posible way to do it programatically

Answer (score 0):

I think the only solution is to create a service in init.rc to be able to execute the script with root permisions on Boot.
Apparently Android things doesnt have a solution right know.
Something like:

on property:dev.bootcomplete=1

```
start bootcomplete_handler
```

service bootcomplete_handler /system/bin/sh /system/bin/bc_handler.sh

```
class late_start

user root

group root

disabled

oneshot
```

But dont know if this will work

Answer (score 0):

**Working and discarded options**

**1. Use ADB (working)**

As [answerer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42474815/5019242) by [Onik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3290339/onik) in this post

**2. Use USB API (working)**

As Android API for USB allows *bulkTransfer*, you can code SCSI compatible commands.

You can also try existing libraries such as [libaums](https://github.com/magnusja/libaums), posted by [Phaestion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1495580/phaestion) in response to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43865719/mount-usb-thumb-drive-to-android-things-when-starting-the-activity?rq=1)

**3. Inject shell commands at init.rc at boot.img (NOT working)**

Shell commands can be injected to the init.rc file inside the boot.img (not the init.rc file that you can find in the /root directory). However, given the A-B boot nature of the AndroidThings compilation, I have been unable to make it work.

**4. Add advanced app permissions (NOT working)**

The following permissions seem promising to execute root commands from the app. However, *permission denied error* continues to block the root command execution.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_FORMAT_FILESYSTEMS" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DEVICE_ADMINS" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_USB" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

I even tried to compile an AndroidThings distribution with an app with such permissions but the Android Things console does NOT allow to include the app to the compilation

**5. White list the app (NOT working)**

There is a white list for priviledged apps. However, this white list is placed in a priviledged directory and cannot be overwritten even from the shell command with root user

**6. Install the app at a priviledged location (NOT working)**
Apps installed in priviledged directories can execute root commands. However, AndroidThings does NOT allow to install apps at such locations (even from the shell with root user)

Comment: Would you know how to use the MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS permission? I see many system permissions on the Manifest permissions, and that's cool. But I don't know how to use any unless there's someone who asked already! Do you know a normal procedure to get to know what to do with the permission? (PS: I have the app installed on system partition, so I can have the permission - just have no idea what to do with it) We call hidden APIs (which I have showing too - I can't understand how to mess with IStorageManager...) or we can directly run supposedly root commands without requesting root?