# Execute Script on Boot Android Things

Tags: android, shell, raspberry-pi, android-things

I am developing with raspberry pi3 on Android Things.
I am trying to execute a Script on boot, modifying `init.rc` file as so:

```
sys.boot_completed = 1:

on property: sys.boot_completed = 1

bootchart stop

# WLD 201805031702

chmod +x /system/bin/myScript.sh //Added by me

sh /system/bin/myScript.sh      //Added by me
```

I don't know why, but the Script doesn't get execute, i have tried to change "hostname anyName" instead of executing the Script on these lines of `init.rc` file, and it does pass throw these lines because hostname get changes, but it doesn't execute the Script.
How can i execute a Script on Boot, i don't know what to do.

Best regards

Alvaro

Answer (score 0):

With Android Things, you can set up your application so that it fits within the Android framework.

For example, if you use the [`HOME`](https://developer.android.com/things/versions/things-1.0) intent filter on your main activity in your app, then your activity will launch immediately on boot, allowing you to run some code.

Comment: But in my script i need to execute some code with root permisions, because i need to mount a partition that Android thing doesnt do, so if i execute it from my app, i cant.
So i need to launch a script on boot that has to be working all the time, mounting a partition when a external mass storage  unit is detected.

Thanks

Comment: @In_va2 The Android Things security model does not currently allow developers to make changes to the system at this level, or to run their apps with root privileges. We have noted the bug you filed on this issue related to mounting storage along with other similar feature request for consideration in future versions.

Comment: and is there any library to be able to work with USB pendrives as mass storage units, manage files, copy files and so? i mean with Android things 1.0 on rpi3?